# Scrolling is too fast with touchpad

Tags: hardware, touchpad

When I try to scroll using the touchpad in VScode it is too fast but if I connect an external mouse it works perfectly and if I use the touchpad on for example notepad it scrolls perfectly.

My laptop is Lenovo IdeaPad L340

Os: Windows 11 but the problem was also on windows 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open regedit, go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> SOFTWARE -> Elantech -> Smartpad, change ScrollControl_Mode from 0 to 1

Comment: bro Thanks so much this will help me a lot !!